# JasperReport : allow large value to be displayed in a textfield

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to display a value in a textField even if the value is larger that the width of the textfield. I don't want it to be truncated.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: you can not set width of  text field to change dynamically. Its better to give width more than required in the beginning only.

Comment: It's not possible to let the text overflow the textfield on the right? I cannot increase the width of the textfield

Comment: The text will be displayed based on width of text-field. If it exceeds the width then the characters going out of the boundary line will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable wrapping text by setting the textField stretchWithOverflow attribute to true. This works as long as the expression time is NOW. It does not work for delayed evaluation.